# Getting URL from request object using net::http

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am creating a request object (my_request) and getting a response from it.

```
  if params[:method].upcase == 'GET'
    my_request = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/' + params[:url]) 
  elsif params[:method].upcase == 'POST'
    my_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/' + params[:url]) 
  elsif params[:method].upcase == 'PUT'
    my_request = Net::HTTP::Put.new('/' + params[:url]) 
  elsif params[:method].upcase == 'DELETE'
    my_request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new('/' + params[:url]) 
  end

  response = http.request(my_request)
```

I want to get the exact URL where my_request is going to make a request. I tried 'fullpath' and original_url, but none of them work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: 1.9.3. I am generating the route but if I have a method that returns a string it will be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Net::HTTP` classes don't have a `fullpath` or `original_url` method or an equivalent. They inherit from [Net::HTTP::GenericRequest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPGenericRequest.html), which has no such method.

Instead, you should use the `path` method. `Net::HTTP` requests don't store a hostname, so if you want to make a valid request, you need to **include the full hostname, not just the path.**

#### Example

```
# Good: complete path
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new('http://example.com/about')
request.path # => 'http://example.com/about'
http.request(request) # => Success

# Bad: incomplete path
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/about')
request.path # => '/about'
http.request(request) # => Error
```

Also, if it were mine, I'd refactor your code to look more like this:

```
url = "http://hostname.com/" + params[:url]
request = case params[:method].upcase
          when 'GET'    then Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
          when 'POST'   then Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
          when 'PUT'    then Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)
          when 'DELETE' then Net::HTTP::Delete.new(url)
          end

http.request(request)
```